# Variable template template?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, template-templates, variable-templates

Say you have a tuple type and you want to extract its template parameter pack in order to instantiate another template. If that is a type template, then I can have a utility like this:

```
template < typename Tuple, template <typename...> typename What >
struct PutTupleInT;

template < typename... Types, template <typename...> typename What >
struct PutTupleInT<std::tuple<Types...>, What>
{
    using Result = What<Types...>;
};
```

But what if the desired template is a variable template? While `template <typename...> typename What` is the "placeholder" for a type template, then what is the "placeholder" for a variable template?

I've tried the following for clang-4.0.0 (the only compiler by now that supports non-type template parameters with auto type), but it failed. Actually I am not sure if this is a correct syntax for C++17.

```
template < typename Tuple, template <typename...> auto What >
struct PutTupleInV;

template < typename... Types, template <typename...> auto What >
struct PutTupleInV<std::tuple<Types...>, What>
{
    static constexpr auto value = What<Types...>;
};
```

Comment: Can't you use `decltype(vartempl)` and extract the type of the variable template, that is what you are interested in actually?

Comment: @skypjack Sorry, I don't really understand  what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Quoting N4606:

> §14.3.3 [temp.arg.template]/1
>
> A *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter* shall be the
>   name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as
>   *id-expression*.

A variable template doesn't fit this requirement.

---

You could cheat a little and use a proxy type to select the template:

```
template < typename Tuple, class Proxy>
struct PutTupleInTV;

template < typename... Types, class Proxy>
struct PutTupleInTV<std::tuple<Types...>, Proxy>
{
    static constexpr auto value = Proxy::template value<Types...>;
};
```

and then for

```
template<typename...> struct foo{};
template<typename... Ts> constexpr foo<Ts...> foo_v{};
struct use_foo
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    static constexpr auto value = foo_v<Ts...>;
};
```

you could say

```
PutTupleInTV<tup, use_foo>::value
```

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SQSgDXjoJHHTj4vj)

Comment: The cheat actually doesn't help much, as it requires the variables to be named "value" and to be placed in a struct.

Comment: @Vahagn yes, you'd have to make proxy structs yourself. I don't see a way around this (doesn't mean there's none, I just don't know of any)

Answer (score 0):

PutTupleInTV is not the same name as PutTupleInV. You are not specializing the template PutTupleInV but using specializing syntax to create something new, called PutTupleInTV.